# Split txt file with open spaces

Tags: python

I'm trying to split a text file in Python but I get the following error:

```
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

My code:

```
for line in lines:
    x, y, e, r, t=line.split()
    return x, y, e, r, t
```

the format of the text file is

```
x y e r t
```

but some lines are missing numbers or letters, for example

```
 x   e r t
 x y   r t
```

So I guess that is why I get the error, but I can't find a way to resolve it.
Is it possible to also count the blank spaces as a variable?

Comment: Are there actual `"` in the file, or are you just pointing out where the character would be?

Comment: Can you give a few more actual examples of the contents of the file? Is it just a single character? Are there words, sentences, with spaces, or other symbols?

Comment: There are no " in the file, it is just a blank space

Comment: example line:      color 1234 place a 5

Comment: also an example for the line missing the number, and please tell us why do you need `for` loop if you are returning the values from the first line only

Comment: replace '' or spaces to NaN

Comment: @omerbp I'm only returning the values to check if it works, it is an school excercise and I need to make an animation on a board with a text file as input so I have to use every line. I'm stuck and I can't find much in the text book about this.

Comment: So what's wrong in returning `line.split()`, and just before doing what you want to do with it check for its lenght? `if len(line.split())==5 .... else .....`

Comment: OP please clarify the format of your file, the initial `"` marker was unclear.  Between `x` and `e` (and `y` and `r`) how many spaces are there?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> 'x   e r t'.replace('  ', ' _').split(' ')
['x', '_', 'e', 'r', 't']
>>> 'x y   r t'.replace('  ', ' _').split(' ')
['x', 'y', '_', 'r', 't']
>>> 'x     r t'.replace('  ', ' _').split(' ')
['x', '_', '_', 'r', 't']
```

And then just check for the special value `'_'` that signalizes a missing value.

Comment: It would probably be safer to do `.replace(' \x20 ', ' _ ')` so as to not accidentally match the two-space case.

Comment: @dimo414 If you do that, the third test case won’t work.

Comment: Hmm fair, though that wasn't one of OPs examples.  A lookahead regex would work, e.g. `re.sub(r' \x20(?= )',' _','x \x20 \x20 r t').split(' ')`, but if the inputs are simple enough that's arguably overkill.

Answer (score 2):

*This answer assumes the lines are **missing** fields, @Poke's answer assumes the fields have been replaced with a space (leaving three spaces between the other fields).*

The docs on [`.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) tell you everything you need to know.

> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently, splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace with a None separator returns [].

So simply specify `sep=' '` in your call to `.split()`, i.e.:

```
line.split(' ')
```

So that the separator is exactly one space.

```
>>> x, y, e, r, t = "x y e r t".split(' ')
>>> print((x, y, e, r, t))
('x', 'y', 'e', 'r', 't')

>>> x, y, e, r, t = "x  e r t".split(' ')
>>> print((x, y, e, r, t))
('x', '', 'e', 'r', 't')

>>> x, y, e, r, t = "x y  r t".split(' ')
>>> print((x, y, e, r, t))
('x', 'y', '', 'r', 't')
```

Comment: `'x \x20 e r t'.split(' ') == ['x', '', '', 'e', 'r', 't']`

Comment: @poke not sure what you're suggesting, but that returns `False`.

Comment: Meh, multiple subsequent spaces are ignored in inline code; that first string is `'x<space><space><space>e<space>r<space>t'`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the number of spaces between each character is only 1 , and an extra whitespace in between indicates an empty variable. I think your best bet would be to not use `line.split()` function , instead move over each character in the `line` and determine the values you need.

A code like this -

```
lst = []
for line in lines:
    for i in xrange(0,len(line),2):
         if line[i] == ' ':
             lst.append(' ')         # or whatever you use for empty variables
         else:
             lst.append(line[i])
   return lst
```

Then you can unpack the list from whereever you are calling the above function

Comment: This only works on single-character inputs, and also concatenates all lines into the same `lst`.